# Convert to LOWER in Laravel with Postgres query

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-6

I implemented a search method and I want to convert the value from WHERE to lowercase ,but from what I find till now, nothing worked.

This works but for Case Sensitive

```
$query->where('customers.account_name', 'like', '%' . $request->get("filter") . '%')
```

This is one of the things that I tried but is wrong.

```
query->where('LOWER(`example.account_name`)', 'like', '%' . 'LOWER(` . $request->get("filter") . ')' . '%')
```

Comment: You'll need to use a DB::raw('LOWER(` . $request->get("filter") . ')' . '%'); to get this to work, since otherwise the query parser will think the whole thing is a string to be searched for.

Comment: have you thought about using `ilike` instead of `like`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL is `ILIKE` , which is case insensitive, so I don't need that both values to be lower.

```
$query->where('customers.account_name', 'ILIKE', $request->get("filter") )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use SQL logic, like `LOWER()`, you can't use `->where()`, as that is DB agnostic (works for all database configurations).

You can use `->whereRaw()`, but if you change your database type (i.e. mysql to postgres or mongo, etc) it won't work:

```php
$query->whereRaw('LOWER(`example.account_name`) LIKE "%'.strtolower($request->input("filter")).'%"');
```

If you run a `dd($query->toSql())`, you can see the raw SQL the query will generate.

Comment: I am using postgres, I tried this and I got an error. Is another way to use LOWER, if whereRaw is not ok?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: ` character varying
LINE 1: ...\"id\" = \"example_names\".\"customer_id\" where LOWER(`customers...

Comment: Might have to switch around the quotes (`'` and `"`). Can you provide the raw postgres query that would work for this?

Comment: I tried to change " , ' , ` ,but I get the same error. the query that works is in description. but without LOWER. , or you want the dd($query->toSql()) ?

Comment: I mean what would you write in your postgres program to generate the expected output? I'm talking the raw, manual query **you would type out**. I don't know postgres enough to tell you what that error means, but if I can see what you're supposed to use, I might be able to modify it.

Comment: I write all query's directly in laravel. I will try in postgres and I will come back, thank you!

Comment: I found what I need. I just use ILIKE instead o LIKE, that way will be case insensitive and will solve my problem, thanks for your time! :)